# Scrapy installation on OSX Lion

Tags: python, osx-lion, scrapy

So I'm trying to install Scrapy on Lion and am not sure if it's properly installed or not.

I followed the guide here http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#intro-install

Then tried to do the first step to create a tutorial project here,

http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html

But when I try to run,

```
scrapy startproject tutorial
```

It doesn't work. I get...

$ python scrapy
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'scrapy': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Any idea why I get such an error?

Comment: What does `which scrapy` return on the command line?

Comment: Empty response, going to try to build and install manually to see what happens...*EDIT* installed manually, still same response. which scrapy results in an empty response.

Comment: No response means `scrapy` is not in your path - I'll respond when I get home and get on my Macbook, as I forget what the regular path is for most of the python add-ons.

Comment: I tried locally with `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install scrapy`, and it put `scrapy` into `/usr/local/bin/scrapy`.

Comment: @birryree if you want to put that as an answer so you will get credit please do :) worked for me!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well turns out it's likely a path issue.

On my Mac, I used `easy_install` from `/usr/bin`.

```
sudo /usr/bin/easy_install scrapy
```

The resulting `scrapy` command is then installed into `/usr/local/bin/scrapy`.

You might not have that directory in your path, so see if that's true with:

```
echo $PATH
```

If it isn't in there, you can temporarily add it like `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`, or modify your `~/.bash_profile` to add it permanently.

---

Alternatively, I typically don't use the system installed Python in Mac - I install homebrew and install a separate version of Python, and install `scrapy` with that version (`scrapy` is then installed into `/usr/local/share/python/scrapy`).

Comment: You're awesome :) Thanks for following up!

Comment: if you don't know where your scrapy is installed, try `sudo find / -name scrapy` and then add it to your path