# centos6.3 install scrapy failed,bash: scrapy: command not found

Tags: python, centos, scrapy

I install all package:

now I have a test:

```
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
    exit()

    [root@dev site-packages]# scrapy
    bash: scrapy: command not found
```

how to do?thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you install scrapy? easy_install? Or pip install? Or python install setup.py? It should be the path problem. You need to install the bin/scrapy script to a directory in the PATH, like /usr/local/bin.

Here is a similar question: [Scrapy installation on OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490303/scrapy-installation-on-osx-lion)