# Trouble Installing Scrapy on 10.9 Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, scrapy, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to install Scrapy using my homebrew python build. Despite having everything up to date, installed and in my path, I cant use it.

Here's my order of operations:

check brew:

```
$ brew doctor
Your system is ready to brew.
```

check python & pip:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ pip -- version
pip 1.5.4 from /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.4-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

(is this normal? this looks like there's two copies, possibly conflicting )

ive already install scrapy but when i try again i get:

```
$ pip install scrapy
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Twisted>=10.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): w3lib>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): queuelib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pyOpenSSL in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): cssselect>=0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): zope.interface>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.2-py2.7.egg (from zope.interface>=3.6.0->Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
Cleaning up...
```

this is weird to me because i expect my modules to be installed in `/usr/local/share/python` NOT in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` 
sure enough, there is no scrapy in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` but there is in `/usr/local/share/python`.

ive added `/usr/local/share/python/scrapy`to my path as discussed here: [Scrapy installation on OSX Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490303/scrapy-installation-on-osx-lion)

but `which scrapy` returns blank.

the most interesting part is when i try to 'update' scrapy using `pip install --upgrade scrapy` :

```
~ ∮ pip install --upgrade scrapy
Requirement already up-to-date: scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: Twisted>=10.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: w3lib>=1.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: queuelib in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking lxml from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/l/lxml/lxml-3.3.2.tar.gz#md5=a3ea7bf74b718ecb46d9fd5198eec92d (from scrapy)
  Downloading lxml-3.3.2.tar.gz (3.5MB): 3.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/lxml/setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.3.2.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.28

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Downloading/unpacking pyOpenSSL from https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyOpenSSL/pyOpenSSL-0.14.tar.gz#md5=8579ff3a1d858858acfba5f046a4ddf7 (from scrapy)
  Downloading pyOpenSSL-0.14.tar.gz (128kB): 128kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/pyOpenSSL/setup.py) egg_info for package pyOpenSSL

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
Requirement already up-to-date: cssselect>=0.9 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.5.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from scrapy)
Requirement already up-to-date: zope.interface>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
Downloading/unpacking cryptography>=0.2.1 (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Downloading cryptography-0.2.1.tar.gz (13.8MB): 13.8MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/cryptography/setup.py) egg_info for package cryptography
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found

    Installed /private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/cryptography/cffi-0.8.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg
    Searching for pycparser
    Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/
    Best match: pycparser 2.10
    Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.10.tar.gz#md5=d87aed98c8a9f386aa56d365fe4d515f
    Processing pycparser-2.10.tar.gz
    Writing /var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/easy_install-qqW3QR/pycparser-2.10/setup.cfg
    Running pycparser-2.10/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/easy_install-qqW3QR/pycparser-2.10/egg-dist-tmp-pniw4C
    zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...

    Installed /private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/cryptography/pycparser-2.10-py2.7.egg

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/cryptography/setup.py", line 113, in <module>
        "build": cffi_build,
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "<string>", line 15, in replacement_run
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 186, in find_sources
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 246, in run
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 282, in add_defaults
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 167, in add_defaults
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 26, in finalize_options
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_py.py", line 46, in finalize_options
        ('force', 'force'))
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 298, in set_undefined_options
        src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/cryptography/setup.py", line 52, in finalize_options
        from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, padding
      File "cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 18, in <module>
        import six
    ImportError: No module named six
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found



Installed /private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/cryptography/cffi-0.8.1-py2.7-macosx-10.9-x86_64.egg

Searching for pycparser

Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pycparser/

Best match: pycparser 2.10

Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pycparser/pycparser-2.10.tar.gz#md5=d87aed98c8a9f386aa56d365fe4d515f

Processing pycparser-2.10.tar.gz

Writing /var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/easy_install-qqW3QR/pycparser-2.10/setup.cfg

Running pycparser-2.10/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/easy_install-qqW3QR/pycparser-2.10/egg-dist-tmp-pniw4C

zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...



Installed /private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/cryptography/pycparser-2.10-py2.7.egg

running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info

writing requirements to pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt

writing pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/cryptography/setup.py", line 113, in <module>

    "build": cffi_build,

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "<string>", line 15, in replacement_run

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 186, in find_sources

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 246, in run

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 282, in add_defaults

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 167, in add_defaults

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command

    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized

    self.finalize_options()

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-x86_64/egg/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 26, in finalize_options

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/build_py.py", line 46, in finalize_options

    ('force', 'force'))

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 298, in set_undefined_options

    src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_pauluslabuser/cryptography/setup.py", line 52, in finalize_options

    from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, padding

  File "cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py", line 18, in <module>

    import six

ImportError: No module named six

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/22/6lh7b3m53zx1xslwtkdk5v400000gp/T/pip_build_myAccount/cryptography
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/myAccount/.pip/pip.log
~ ∮
```

I've tried remedying some of these such as, `pip install six` and tried googling this `egg_info failed with error code 1`. 
most solutions involve not having setuptools installed, yet:

```
$ pip install setuptools
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-2.2-py2.7.egg
Cleaning up...
```

it looks like my brew install of python and incorrect linking/multiple versions? of pip are causing modules to be installed in one place while my python is somewhere else (this explains why `>>> import scrapy` fails but not why `$ scrapy` fails ).

a similar post about broken python modules suggests running `xcode-select --install` which I've confirmed are up to date. [Can't install PIL after Mac OS X 10.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532125/cant-install-pil-after-mac-os-x-10-9)

maybe its virtualenv time?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, virtualenv will probably sort a lot of these problems

Comment: hmmm... I have done this already without using homebrew... just do a `sudo pip install scrapy` (sudo because usually mac permissions are messed up), and it **should** work... unless your computer is having issues.

Comment: @aj8uppal I get the same results as when I use `pip install scrapy`
I have another laptop without homebrew and your suggestion works (I get the command line function but not the python import) 
However on this computer scrapy is not recognized at the command line nor is it recognized by python `>>> import scrapy`

Comment: @hd1 i've tried installing `virtualenv` to about the same effect as `scrapy`. 
I followed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860971/cant-pip-install-virtualenv-in-os-x-10-8-with-brewed-python-2-7
followed the first answer and:
`~ ∮ pip install virtualenv

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...

~ ∮ virtualenv test

-bash: virtualenv: command not found`

Comment: Are you using the full path to scrapy when executing? If not, try that.

Comment: @hd1 scrapy isnt where pip says it is: 
`pip install scrapy

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scrapy in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

but it's not there.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Since you're using Homebrew as your package manager, the the programs installed through it will be set to `/usr/local/bin` rather than the standard `/usr/bin` path setting for out of the box applications. You'll want to ensure that `/usr/local/bin` is at the top of the file in `/etc/paths`. The file should be locked, so you may need to save changes in the vi editor with the following:

   ```
   :w !sudo tee %
   ```
2. `$ which python` should return `/usr/local/bin/python`, else:

   ```
   `$ brew unlink python`
   `$ brew install python`
   `$ brew linkapps`
   ```
3. `$ which pip` should return `/usr/local/bin/pip`, else

   ```
   `$ brew install pip`
   ```
4. Then...

   ```
   `$ sudo pip uninstall Scrapy`
   `$ pip install Scrapy`
   `$ pip install --upgrade Scrapy`
   `$ pip install --upgrade lxml`
   `$ scrapy startproject tutorial`
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue installing `virtualenv`: [Can't pip install virtualenv on Mac 10.9 Mavericks with brewed python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22394580/cant-pip-install-virtualenv-on-mac-10-9-mavericks-with-brewed-python)

the solution there works here as well, although I still do not understand WHY the problem occurred in the first place and why this solution works. But it does.

uninstall and reinstall scrapy:

```
$pip uninstall scrapy
$pip install scrapy
```

This removes modules from `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`
and installs them in `/usr/local/bin/`

The problem is that according to the homebrew python docs, pip is suppose to install in `/site-packages` and they should work. 
Not only does it not work with them in `/site-packages` but pip defaults to installing in `/usr/local/bin/`.

This workaround works, although I would really appreciate an explanation as to why it works and why this was a problem in the first place. Then perhaps these two questions can be merged?

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me in OS X 10.10 Yosemite.

But I found a solution [here](http://blog.felipe-alfaro.com/2014/10/31/installing-python-glanceclient-using-brew-on-mac-os-x-10-10/).

It's using pkg-config:

```
brew install pkg-config libffi
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/pkgconfig/
pip install cffi
```

You will have to change the path according to your libffi version.

Comment: This worked for me as well in 10.9 Mavericks. used `locate libffi.pc` to find mine: `/usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.0.13/lib/pkgconfig/libffi.pc`

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your installation environment access to the Crypto library bundled with OpenSSL. Here is the solution that worked for me.

env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

Remember to change this to the location of your updated OpenSSL package.

Answer (score 0):

The other posts didn't work for me, but this did:

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS=-Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future pip install scrapy
```